# Endpoint Or GraphQL to upload Image files In a location where File Under Content using Python

Tags: python, graphql, shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api

I'm trying to find out how to upload image files on Files under content using API or GraphQL on shopify.

*Note: I dont't want to upload image files to a specific product,but to a files section.*
[files section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXMtu.png)

I asked Claunde2 and it says;
To upload an image file to the Files section in Shopify using the REST Admin API, you would use the following endpoint:

```
POST /admin/api/2023-10/themes/<theme_id>/assets.json
```

I have tried it but it didn't work.

Please tell me endpoint or GraphQL to do.

Answer (score 0):

If the file is already uploaded to a known url then the GraphQL mutation is this:

[fileCreate](https://shopify.dev/docs/api/admin-graphql/2024-01/mutations/fileCreate)

Shopify will copy the file and it will appear on the files section.

But if you want to upload to Shopify then the process is a little complicated. The flow is like this:

1. Get a handle on the file (maybe using [Drop zone](https://polaris.shopify.com/components/selection-and-input/drop-zone))
2. Create a staged upload target using [stagedUploadsCreate](https://shopify.dev/docs/api/admin-graphql/2024-01/mutations/stageduploadscreate). Input fields will be the values you get from the file handle.
3. Upload the file to the staged target using the url and parameters you get from the previous step and [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData).
4. Create the file on Shopify using [fileCreate](https://shopify.dev/docs/api/admin-graphql/2024-01/mutations/fileCreate). originalSource needs to be the resourceUrl you get from the staged target data. Returned file id will be a file_reference so you can use it later on different queries.

Some links I learned all these:

- https://community.shopify.com/c/graphql-basics-and/full-process-for-uploading-files-to-the-files-api/m-p/1423503
- https://shopify.dev/docs/apps/online-store/media/products
- https://www.shopify.com/partners/blog/upload-files-graphql-react

If there is something missing or wrong because the process has changed after I posted this, please add a comment so I can edit my answer.